# jQuery focusout exception

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input

I would need help with jQuery. I have input, where I have sub menu. And I want to if input is active, sub menu be visible, and where I focus out the input, menu should display none. It works fine, but I have in sub menu links, which does not work, because they disappear before they do their action.

```
<div class="searchBeer col-100">
<input id="beerName" type="text" class="col-95">
<a href="#" class="searchbtn col-5"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></a>
</div>
<ul id="autocomplete" class="col-100" style="display: none;">
<li class="row"><a href="#" class="col-100">Plzen</a></li>
<li class="row"><a href="#" class="col-100">Plzen</a></li>
</ul>
```

Javascript:

```
$$('#beerName').focus(function () {
    $('.searchBeer').addClass('input-active');
    $('#autocomplete').show();
});
$$('#autocomplete a').click(function () {
    alert($(this).text());
});

$$('#beerName').focusout(function () {

    $('.searchBeer').removeClass('input-active');
    $('#autocomplete').hide();
});
```

Can you help me?

Comment: Why do you have double `$$` in some places?

Comment: i think you are logically not cleared. you want that sub menu will hide as soon as you loss focus and at the same time you want to select item from sub menu? then how can you select item from menu without losing focus from input

Comment: I would like this. If I focus out the input than sub menu will every time display none. Only If I click on link in submenu, jquery alert value of links before sub menu will display none.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this using `mouseover` event.[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/suchit/zpmd4j2x/)

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="searchBeer col-100">
<input id="beerName" type="text" class="col-95">
<a href="#" class="searchbtn col-5"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></a>
</div>
<ul id="autocomplete" class="col-100" style="display: none;">
<li class="row"><a href="#" class="col-100">Plzen</a></li>
<li class="row"><a href="#" class="col-100">Plzen</a></li>
</ul>
<script>

$('#beerName').focus(function () {
    $('.searchBeer').addClass('input-active');
    $('#autocomplete').show();
});
$('#autocomplete a').on("mouseover",function (e) {  
    alert($(this).text());
 $('.searchBeer').removeClass('input-active');//if not required remove this and the below line
    $('#autocomplete').hide();
});

$('#beerName').focusout(function () {
    $('.searchBeer').removeClass('input-active');
    $('#autocomplete').hide();
});



</script>
```